# Imprimindo Porcentagem

Tags: javascript

Tentei fazer um algoritmo pra imprimir a porcentagem de cada tipo de voto, mas meu codigo dá erro por alguma razao, alguem consegue me explicar o porque?
Segue abaixo:

```
/*Escreva um algoritmo para ler o número total de eleitores de
um município, o número de votos brancos, nulos e válidos. Calcular e escrever
o percentual que cada um representa em relação ao total de eleitores.*/

var eleitores = 34
var vbrancos = 16
var vnulos = 8
var vvalidos = 10

vbpercentual = (100 * vbrancos) / eleitores
vnpercentual = (100 * vnulos) / eleitores
vvpercentual = (100 * vvalidos) / eleitores

console.log('Votos em Branco: ' vbpercentual)
console.log('Votos Nulos: ' vnpercentual)
console.log('Votos Válidos: ' vvpercentual)
```

Comment: Você não criou as variáveis `vbpercentual`, `vnpercentual` e `vvpercentual`. Precisa iniciar com a tag `var` se for criar uma variável nova. Fazer desse jeito funciona, mas cria globais implícitas, o que é ruim para seu código e se estiver rodando num validador automático de um site, pode causar erro.
Além disso, para passar mais de um argumento no `console.log()` deve concatenar com `+` ou virgula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo podemos observar a [documentação do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Console) para a funcionalidade `console`, podemos passar vários argumentos pelo `console.log()`, desde que estejam separados por vírgula.

```js
var eleitores = 34;
var vbrancos = 16;

vbpercentual = (100 * vbrancos) / eleitores;
console.log('Votos em Branco: ', vbpercentual);
```